# How to capture null in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i try to detect null this way

```
if(!$(this))
{
    alert('here is null');
}

OR

if($(this)===null)
{
    alert('here is null');
}
```

but still no luck.

### here is partial code

```
$elements.each(function(){
//alert($(this).html());
    var $item = $('<li />').append($(this));
    if(!$(this))
    {
        alert('here is null');
    }
    //alert($item.text());
    $list.append($item);
});
```

anyone can see full code from here https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/41s1pq3a/12/

### edit

i was iterate in td's content. td has some link and text. i was trying to wrap each text and link inside li. so iterate this below way. code is working but some time it is also showing null which i need to detect.

i am looking for way not consider any null or empty.

### here is the code

```
var $elements = $('.webgrid-footer td').contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 || this.nodeType === 1; // 1 means elements, 3 means text node
  });

var $list = $('<ul />');

$elements.each(function(){
//alert($(this).html());
    var $item = $('<li />').append($(this));
    if(this===null)
    {
        alert('here is null');
    }
    //alert($item.text());
    $list.append($item);
});
//alert($list.html());
$('#dv').append($list);
```

see this line `var $item = $('<li />').append($(this));` it is getting some time empty or null which i do not want tp consider. if anyone knows it how to handle this situation then share the idea. thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  I doubt `this` will *ever* be `null`.  (And an initialized jQuery object certainly won't be.)

Comment: A jQuery object will never be null, even if `this` is `null`, hence the reason your `if` condition never hits. That being said, it's really not clear what you're trying to achieve. Can you describe what your goal is.

Comment: why you think that one of elements should be null?

Comment: $(this)!==null use it. because every current object holding something.

Comment: you can write if($(this).length==0) alert('here is null')

Comment: why you use `contents()`? you not need it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(null)` is an empty jQuery object, not `null`. And all objects are truthy.

If you want to test null, use `this === null`. [You don't need jQuery for this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif)

However, I don't see why do you expect `this` to be null sometimes. Instead, it seems you want to ignore whitespace text nodes.

```js
var $elements = $('.webgrid-footer td').contents().filter(function() {
  return (this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) !== '')
         || this.nodeType === 1;
});
```

Comment: i tried this code `if(this===null)
    {
     alert('here is null');
    }` but did not work. it will be helpful if u see my jsfiddle code and rectify there.

Comment: @Mou: No, that's not the way it works. The **full content** of your question must be *in* your question, not just linked.

Comment: @Mou use $(this)===null and if its null then only it will be goes under if statement
What answer oriol gave it's correct.

Comment: @Mou Question must be complete by themselves, without needing to read an external link. And I don't see why do you expect `this` to be null sometimes.

Comment: see the js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/41s1pq3a/24/ i applied your modification in code and now nothing is getting append in div called dv. please see and tell me what is wrong there?

Comment: @Mou `&.trim` was a typo, I meant `$.trim`.

Answer (score 3):

`$(this)` will never be either `null` or falsey, because jQuery always returns an object reference, which is not `null` or falsey.

In **strict mode**, it's possible for `this` (not `$(this)`) to be `null`. In loose mode, it isn't; attempts to make `this` be `null` will cause `this` to be a reference to the global object.

So it may be that you want to test `this`, not `$(this)`. But only in strict mode. In loose mode, bizarrely, you'd want `if (this == window)` to be your "null" test.

Having said that, `$elements` is clearly meant to be a jQuery object, and I'm not immediately thinking of a way to to create a jQuery objct with `null`s in through the public API. (It's easy if you muck about with the internals...)

Comment: see my jsfiddle code and rectify code there like what to write to capture the null. thanks

Comment: @Mou: Put the full content of your question **in** your question, not just linked.